# Driving a motor using SPST relay

Tags: microcontroller, motor, relay, dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor

I'm trying to drive a brushed DC motor of 24V and 7W (sorry I don't have the datasheet) using a power relay on a PCB using a STM32 microcontroller.

My plan is to use my STM32 to control a transistor to drive a [SPST relay](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/J1021AS59VDC-45/14002164)  ([datasheet](https://www.citrelay.com/Catalog%20Pages/RelayCatalog/J102.pdf)) that's connected to the motor. But I'm a little bit confused about the output voltage of the relay. From what I understand from the datasheet of the relay, I'll need a 9V to drive the relay, but what will be the output of the relay? Will it be 9V too? Does it mean I'll need a 24V coil voltage to drive a 24V motor?

Thanks.

Comment: THe relay has four terminals. Two for the coil/magnet that closes the primary contacts. And two for the primary contacts. They are independent as far as voltage and current goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But I'm a little bit confused about the output voltage of the relay.
> From what I understand from the datasheet of the relay, I'll need a 9V
> to drive the relay, but what will be the output of the relay?*

Try this GIF animation from [this site](https://instrumentationtools.com/relay-working-animation/): -

[image]

It uses a 6 volt coil and switches 120 volts AC. Or maybe [this](https://gifimage.net/relais-gif-5/) is more your style: -

[image]

Same coil drive voltage as the output circuit but, the important thing here is that there is galvanic isolation between coil and contacts and, the contacts will run on a wide range of different voltages and AC.

Personally, [this](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/804244445935721199/) is my favourite: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The coil and the switch parts of the relay are isolated from each other electrically. The relay can't have output voltage, you're meant to wire it like a switch into your 24V motor circuit with its own 24V power supply. The coil still needs to be powered by 9V (according to the relay specs), no matter the motor voltage.